# Get the next line after some set characters

Tags: c++

I want to read a .txt file and after finding this specific line...

```
===================
```

... I want to grab the next line.

I think I have to use the `strcmp` and the `fgets` but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: So, do you want to "grab the next line" or do you want to count the number of lines after some character?

Comment: @CoryKlein I want just to grab the next line

Comment: -1 for asking for C++ when you actually meant C.

Answer (score 6):

Simple enough with `std::getline`:

```
const std::string WANTED_LINE = "===================";

std::ifstream file(filename);
std::string line;
while (std::getline(file, line) && line != WANTED_LINE){}

if (std::getline(file, line)) {/*read the line after successfully*/}
```

The for loop goes for as long as the next line is read successfully and is not the one you're looking for. After that, you simply read the next one. If a read failed in the for loop, the one after the loop will also fail.

If, for some reason beyond my understanding, `strcmp` is desired, you can change it minimally:

```
while (std::getline(file, line) && std::strcmp(line.c_str(), WANTED_LINE) != 0){}
```

For a completely C solution, you can do almost the same thing. I did the same thing on [ideone](http://ideone.com/a8bFIQ) with stdin instead of a file (easily changed) and limited lines to 256 characters:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

int main(void) {
    char line[256];
    while (fgets(line, 256, stdin) && strcmp(line, "12345\n") != 0){}
    if (fgets(line, 256, stdin)) {puts(line);}

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

> abc
>   123
>   do re me
>   12345
>   test line
>   hi

Output:

> test line

Comment: @user2600514, You can, but why would you?

Answer (score 0):

My C++ is a bit rusty,  but ISTR the [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) method on iStream should get the line and the [search](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) method on string will find indexes containing a string within a string. A combination of these should do what you want. If not, leave a comment and I'll help out further.

Comment: @user2600514 You asked about C++, so no. Write a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

This would be the C way to do it.

```
#define READBUFF_SIZE 100

FILE * infile = fopen(filename, "r");
char readbuff[READBUFF_SIZE] = "";

while (fgets(readbuff, READBUFF_SIZE, infile)) {
    if (strcmp(readbuff, "===============\n") == 0) break;
}

if (fgets(readbuff, READBUFF_SIZE, infile)) {
    // do something with readbuff
    printf("%s\n", readbuff);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    string line = "";
    fstream f;
    f.open("a.txt");
    int count = 0;
    if (f.is_open())
  {

      while (f.good() )
    {


         getline(f,line);
         if(line=="12345")
         {

            while (f.good() )
             {
                 getline(f,line);
                 count++;
             }

         }
        //You can choose to change this terminatin condition as per your need
         if(count!=0)//Assuming there are line present after the particular line

             break;

    }
    f.close();
  }
else 
  {
      cout << "Unable to open file"; 
  }
    cout<<count;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

input

```
wefwefwefwef
weffwfwefwe
wefwefwefwef
12345
fwefwef
wefwefwef
```

Output :2

```
 2
```